# Inline asm: move imm to a 64-bit register without sign-extension

Tags: c, x86-64, inline-assembly

I want to move a 64-bit unsigned integer to a register using inline asm. What happens is the constant gets sign-extended if it in fact fits in 32 bits.

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdint.h"
uint64_t foo() {
    uint64_t x;
    asm ("movq %1, %0"
         : "=q" (x)
         : "i" (0x00000000faceffff) );
    return x;
}
```

Now, `clang -S code.c` produces the following assembly:

```
#APP    
movq    $-87097345, %rax        # imm = 0xFFFFFFFFFACEFFFF
#NO_APP
```

Same thing for gcc. Same thing for `movabsq` in place of `movq`. Same for `"p"` constraint instead of `"i"`.

I get the result I expect if the constant is larger than 32 bits.

Comment: deleted previous comment as it's now in the answer. Will delete this comment later.

Comment: If it fits in 32 bits you don't need a 64bit mov in the first place.

Comment: @harold, I do need it, because in my real use case I'll want to patch the constant which is 64 bit in general (an address).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a suffix for constants to declare them as unsigned long long with gcc? With Microsoft compilers it's "...ull" in this case 0x00000000faceffffull.

Comment: It almost makes me wonder if the example was chosen knowing what the answer would be!

Comment: @Hurkyl, LOL. No, this was totally unintentional :)

Comment: My mistake was I forgot `0x00000000faceffff` is a C-constant, not just some string. The answer is correct regardless of the compiler, `ull` is a prefix for `unsigned long long int` according to the standard (en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal).